# How to compile/freeze a python 3.3.2

Tags: python

What program can I use to make a stand-alone EXE of a python program? and how would I use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use py2exe 
http://www.py2exe.org

And there's a tutorial on how to use it on their site 
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

It converts runnable python scripts to exe executables so the user doesn't even have to install python just run the file

Comment: Does this work with python 3.3.2?

Comment: The site does not explicitly say yes or no, but does mention pyhton 3. You can always try it and see